# Sorting with Selection sort in Java

Tags: java, sorting, selection-sort

My Homework Assignment was to do this

For the array below, demonstrate the steps (passes) for the Selection and Insertion Sorts:

5 2 3 1 6 9 8

Be sure to write out the original array, and what it looks like after each pass.

I am getting a weird if statement error.

> My error says = Illegal start of type. At a position in the source
>   where the type was expected there was something else, most likely a
>   java keyword. Check this line for incorrect definiton types

. Can anyone help me please. Below is my code

```
import java.util.*;
public class Selection_Sort
{
final int[] myArray = { 5, 2, 3, 1, 6, 8, 9 };
int min;
{
  int min, temp;

  for (int index = 0; index < myArray.length-1; index++)
  {
     min = index;
     for (int scan = index+1; scan < myArray.length; scan++)
        if (myArray[scan] < myArray[min])
           min = scan;
     temp = myArray[min];
     myArray[min] = myArray[index];
     myArray[index] = temp;
  }
}
if (min !=i)
     {
        final int temp = myArray[i];
        myArray[i] = myArray[min];
        myArray[min] = temp;
    }
    System.out.println(myArray[i]);
 }
```

Comment: Where do you define `i`? What is the error.

Comment: Is there a method missing in your source code?

Comment: Please always post any and all error messages.

Comment: The code you have posted has an abundance of syntax errors.

Comment: I added the error i was recieving.

Answer (score 0):

After just cleaning up your syntax errors and making a best guess of what you meant with your code structure, this is the result:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Selection_Sort {
  final static int[] myArray = { 5, 2, 3, 1, 6, 8, 9 };

  public static void main(String[] args){
    int min, temp;

    for (int index = 0; index < myArray.length-1; index++) {
       min = index;
       for (int scan = index+1; scan < myArray.length; scan++){
        if (myArray[scan] < myArray[min]){
           min = scan;
         }
      }

      temp = myArray[min];
      myArray[min] = myArray[index];
      myArray[index] = temp;

      if (min != index) {
        temp = myArray[index];
        myArray[index] = myArray[min];
        myArray[min] = temp;
      }
      System.out.println(myArray[index]);
    }
  }
}
```

The output of the program isn't what you want, but this is a starting point for you.

Once you take a look at this and see what a valid program looks like, then you can start making changes to your code to make it do what you want.

Here are some tips:

- make incremental changes
- try to always have a working copy of the code before you start adding features
- when you're first making code, use lots and lots of print statements to help you visualize what's going on